# LSTM In keras, I can't found Weight of cell term in Keras code

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I confuse with Lstm in Keras.
I try to map keras code to LSTM equation.
I found this weights parameter in Keras code.
[LSTM Keras code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3W7b.png)

I think that It's a weights from current weight of cell and recurrent weight of cell.

In the call function in LSTM Keras code
I found the statement for calculate i,f,c and o term . 
[calculate I,F,C,O term Lstm in keras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFXq8.png)

In i term of LSTM equation have W_ci * C_t-1 but I can't find in Keras code.

Could please anyone explain the LSTM equation and Keras code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the LSTM equation please follow this link
[LSTM equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py8Yj.png)